# No HTTPS responce after installing RapidSSL certificate on Glassfish

Tags: glassfish, ssl-certificate

I have got a RapidSSL certificat and trying to install it on my Glassfish 4.0.
When I change Certificate NickName for http-listener-2 from s1as to saljex the server stops responding to https-requests.

My procedure:

> openssl req -sha256 -new -key domain.key -out domain.csr

Order RapidSSL with domain.csr, copy the received certificate to file cert.txt.

> keytool -import -alias saljex -keystore keystore.jks -trustcacerts -file cert.txt

Logging in to glassfish admin and change Certificate NickName for http-listener-2 from s1as to saljex.

Server stops responding to https-requests, and starts responding if I change back to s1as.

Trying to change all references in domain.xlm from s1as to saljex and now also admin-port stops responding.

I cant find any information in he log files.

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Customer support mentioned that I forgot to import my private key. I don't know exactly what I did, but the key was the key.